# How to access django choice field tuple in view?

Tags: python, django

I have a model as below:

```
class EmployeeJobPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True, choices=YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE_CHOICES)

YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE_CHOICES = (
    (0, '0-1 Years'),
    (1, '1+ Years'),
    (5, '5+ Years'),
    (10, '10+ Years'),
)
```

How can I access YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE_CHOICES in a django view ?

Comment: @nim4n that's just plain wrong.

Comment: @nim4n no, that's not true

Comment: oh sorry I think he want to access It in template!

Comment: need some more explanation for better answers..

Answer (score 3):

```
instance.get_years_of_experience_display()
```

Comment: Isn't it `get_years_of_experience_display()`?

Comment: Nah, I was really unsure, you're the man when it comes to Django around these here parts! :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you were looking to get the tuple of choices instead of just the currently selected display value, you can access the model's field through the instance's _meta attribute.

```
instance = EmployeeJobPost.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
choices = dict(instance._meta.get_field_by_name('years_of_experience')[0].flatchoices)
```

Now you can access all of the other options, aside from the currently selected one. `choices.get(0)`, `choices.get(2)`, etc. Otherwise, you can create a form field object and access the choices from there. The other thing you can do is import the constant from your models.py module.

```
from my_app.models import YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE_CHOICES

choices = dict(YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: This helped me , but did it a little bit different: dict(instance._meta.get_field_by_name('years_of_experience').flatchoices)